# Calendar Intent Android

Tags: android, calendar

I need to create a calendar intent that inserts a calendar event with the begin and end times specified by the same String variable (named `fechafin`). This is the code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fechafin = String.valueOf(dateDisplay.getText());

    insert();

    Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Events.CONTENT_URI);
    calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, fechafin);
    calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, fechafin);
    calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false);
    calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, objetivocaja);

    startActivity(calendarIntent);

}
```

If you try this, when the calendar starts, the start and end dates are always 01/01/1970, but I need the date save in **fechafin**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `fechafin` has the value 0. That is equivalent to an epoch date of 1/1/1970.

Can you add logging statements, or debug the code to verify what the value of `fechafin` actually is?

Comment: How do I to add a Log?